# Frontity Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, frontity

I am new to the use of Frontity, but I do have a few questions, I hope this is the right place for it!.

Can someone explain me how to :

List products with Frontity.

Show variable products with Frontity

The use of REST API in Frontity.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know

Comment: Question belongs to the Frontity forum. However, the good news is that Frontity has been acquired by Automattic and they are working with the WooCommerce team to extend Frontity to support WC using its new Store API.

Answer (score -1):

Here is where you put in the API - its basically just your website URL plus wp-json.

```
"name": "@frontity/wp-source",
  "state": {
    "source": {
      "api": "https://test.frontity.org/wp-json"
    }
```